# Cleaner way to iterate through array + create a string from values

Tags: go

With this code, is there a better way to loop through all the users and create a new string containing all their `Nick` values?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Nick     string
}


func main() {
    var users [2]User
    users[0] = User{ Nick: "Radar" }
    users[1] = User{ Nick: "NotRadar" }
    names := ":"
    for _, u := range users {
        names += u.Nick + " "
    }
    fmt.Println(names)

}
```

Comment: What's your problem with this method? It seems pretty standard to me (maybe you want to use strings.TrimSpace(names) or names[:len(names)-1] in some cases, though, to lop off that extra trailing space).

Comment: Well, I'm a Ruby programmer and in Ruby I would just do `users.map(&:name).join(' ')`. I thought there may be something obvious in Go that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really looks like you want a [strings.Join](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) here.  You probably want to avoid that tight loop of repeated string concatenations in the original code; I'm fairly certain that Go doesn't implement a [rope-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) data structure for its primitive strings.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type User struct {
    Nick string
}

func main() {
    var users [2]User
    users[0] = User{Nick: "Radar"}
    users[1] = User{Nick: "NotRadar"}
    userNames := []string{}
    for _, u := range users {
        userNames = append(userNames, u.Nick)
    }
    names := ":" + strings.Join(userNames, " ")
    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. I should've thought about that. Great idea :)

Comment: Using strings.Join is rather superfluous here. If you look at the source for Join, it basically does a fancier variant of the sample code in the question, but rather than concatenation with "+=" it uses the builtin copy() function. You're essentially just doubling your work with strings.Join. At the very least if you're going to do this you should replace userNames := []string{} with userNames := make([]string, 0, len(users)) since otherwise "append" suffers the same problem as "+=" does with strings.

Comment: No, this is effectively different.  `strings.Join` does a single allocation of a string the combined size of all the joined strings (lines 364-366 of http://golang.org/src/pkg/strings/strings.go).  That has a much different efficiency vs a repeated allocation of a larger and larger string.  Think "Gauss sum", and you'll understand the fundamental reason why.  The note about declaring the capacity of userNames is fine, but append() is smarter about how it expands based on well-known dynamic array expansion algorithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array.

Comment: @Jsor: Could you provide an answer on this question with the code you're talking about so that I can understand?

Comment: I should add that peterSO's answer is also very right: it avoids the same pitfall about repeated string concatenation, and is more flexible than my solution.  It's probably best if we merge the two answers.

Answer (score 5):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Nick string
}

func main() {
    var users [2]User
    users[0] = User{Nick: "Radar"}
    users[1] = User{Nick: "NotRadar"}
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    buf.WriteByte(':')
    for _, u := range users {
        buf.WriteString(u.Nick)
        buf.WriteByte(' ')
    }
    names := buf.String()
    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

This avoids a lot of allocations due to the concatenation of `string`s.

You could also write:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Nick string
}

func main() {
    var users [2]User
    users[0] = User{Nick: "Radar"}
    users[1] = User{Nick: "NotRadar"}
    var buf []byte
    buf = append(buf, ':')
    for _, u := range users {
        buf = append(buf, u.Nick...)
        buf = append(buf, ' ')
    }
    names := string(buf)
    fmt.Println(names)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not know of a more elegant way to write that code.

Go does have a [String.Join](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) method so if you made a helper that converted your array of users to a slice of strings (`[]string`) then you could pass that to `String.Join`.

I think that Go's static typing and lack of templates makes it hard to write a general purpose `map` function like Ruby has.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was talking about in the comments of dyoo's post. Effectively a rewrite of join to prevent having to iterate over the list an extra time and allocate an extra slice.

```
func Usernames(users []User) string {
    if len(users) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    if len(users) == 1 {
        return users[0].Name
    }

    sep := " "
    n := len(users)-1 // From len(sep) * len(a)-1, sep is always len 1 unlike in Join
    for i := 0; i < len(users); i++ {
        n += len(users[i].Name)
    }

    names := make([]byte,n)
    namesp := copy(names, users[0].Name)
    for _,u := range users[1:] {
        namesp += copy(names[namesp:], sep)
        namesp += copy(names[namesp:], u.Name)
    }
    return string(names)
}
```

For reference, strings.go with the strings.Join source: 
http://golang.org/src/pkg/strings/strings.go

See line 356

Comment: I recommend avoiding this inlining of `strings.Join` unless the profiler has told us that it's going to help us significantly.  Optimizations without measurement or data to back them up can turn awry.  Not using the standard library means missing out on any future improvements to those libraries.